# How to disable New Task buttons and Other Action buttons from Activity Time Line Component in Lightning Flexi Page

Tags: lightning-experience, tasks, flexipages, activity-timeline

We are working to leverage 'Activity Time Line Component' on the Flexi page to let users see the open task and act on them, at the same time we want to remove the 'New Task' and if possible other buttons as well fro the Activity time line for business reasons and let users use the custom buttons on the related list to create these records.

[image]

Is there a way to remove these buttons from the standard Activity Timeline component?

As the help [links](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activity_timeline_parent.htm&type=5) from salesforce doesn't say anything about customizing/removing these buttons, but we have observed few users sharing the same Flexi page with different profiles are not seeing these buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Lightning Action buttons from the Page Layout and that should do the trick.

[image: Page Layout configuration]

[image: Updated record detail page w/out 'New Task' and 'Log a Call' actions]